# android google maps mapview button bug

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps

I'm using google maps - mapview in my app. My values are

```
"latitude": 51.5037564,
"longitude": -0.0001575
```

I create my `LatLng` object with this values and set like this.

```
val marker = location?.let { MarkerOptions().position(it) }

marker?.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_marker))

map?.addMarker(marker)
```

It works perfectly in my map, marker displays at correct location.

But when I tap onto this button

[image: this button]

Wrong coordinats with scientific notation displays in google maps

[image: like this.]

Google maps displays toast that says "no results for 51.5037564, -1.57E-4"

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Java decide to optimize `-0.0001575` cutting down zeros and adding `E-n` at the end of the number where `n` = amount of cutted zeros. To see this transformation you could print your coordinate in log. I don't have Google maps code so I just guessing when you open Google maps app the coordinates sending there like a `String` and this `String` have to be parsed to `double` because of `E` and `-` symbols.
If you wan't to fix your case remove one of the zero in your longitude. To avoid this behavior you have to avoid 0.000... coordinate validate it or something else.

Comment: No it must show marker, for other coordinates it works correctly, google maps displays toast that says "no results for 51.300, -1.57E-4"

Comment: I have thousands of coordinates given by user so not sure this way works for me or not.

Comment: @EmreAkcan your question sounds like "What can be the problem?". And I described where your problem is. " -1.57E-4" not a coordinate for google map.